# How To Use Minecart tracks In Terraria Mobile

Tags: terraria-mobile

I recently got onto Terraria and updated it to find a new thing called Minecart tracks. However, I couldn't find Minecarts. How do you use the Minecart tracks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Try placing some track and then grappling it](https://youtu.be/Zj2WyJerdY8?t=18s).  It looks like in the mobile game you have a minecart by default.

Comment: actually not true. You tap on it and a grapple type thing appears that is not a real grapple.

Answer (score 3):

Just tapping it. Then it shoots a grapple type thing (not your grapple)

And voila! you're on a minecart!